# MediaElement in WinRT / Win8 does not work at all

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm getting really frustrated with WinRT (Windows 8 apps). I've been running into a lot of problems with the most basic functionality and no documentation to support it.

So, here's my next question of the series I've already posted regarding WinRT:

```
<MediaElement Width="500" 
              Height="500"
              Source="ms-appx:///Assets/SampleVideo.wmv" />
```

**Why doesn't this work?!!!**

- No video displays.
- No audio played.
- No error messages.
- No exceptions thrown.

**None of these events are raised:**

- MediaOpened
- MediaFailed
- MediaEnded
- SeekCompleted
- DownloadProgressChanged
- BufferingProgressChanged

The only event raised is *CurrentStateChanged* which happens when the State  is "Opening". And that's it. Nothing else happens.

I tried doing it manually using a stream like this:

```
var packageLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var assetsFolder = await packageLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var myVideo = await assetsFolder.GetFileAsync("SampleVideo.wmv");
var stream = await myVideo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

_Player.SetSource(stream, myVideo.ContentType);
_Player.Play();
```

**This doesn't work either.** Same inactivity.

The *SampleVideo.wmv* file is build type *Content* and I can open it fine in Windows Media Player and Zune. So there's absolutely no problems with the video file. However, I did try other files, like MP4, AVI, etc. Nothing works.

Is anyone else having problems? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a sample in the Dev Center (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be) that I used by plugging in your XAML and including a WMV file as a local asset, and it worked fine - perhaps stepping through the sample and comparing with your code will help identify the issue?

Comment: @JimO'Neil, the sample doesn't work either. I downloaded it before and tested every possible video file out there. Nothing plays. No error messages or exceptions thrown. I have 3 different machines running Windows 8, and none of them can run a video file.

Comment: this is Windows 8 RTM and Visual Studio RTM right?

Comment: @JimO'Neil, yes. We have an MSDN license and installed the latest Windows 8 Pro x64 release with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Three different computers are failing to run the most basic MediaElement video.

Comment: and same behavior with the out-of-the-box sample I quoted above, no modifications, in terms of CurrentStateChanged firing but not MediaOpened?

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I can't figure out why. I have the latest drivers installed (which are the windows 7 drivers, they don't exist for windows 8 and probably never will). Is there any way to make it work? Nothing works, not even the sample.

Comment: @Tibi, I wish I had an answer for you. It took me a while to figure out the driver issue. It all stems from the new WinRT MediaPlayer, where it swallows the exception. In your case, if the drivers don't exist, then maybe a new graphics card would help.

Comment: @Laith Thanks for the response. It's not possible to replace the video card since I am using a laptop, and I am definitely not going to buy a new laptop/video card just because MediaElement doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 48 hours of research and painful trial n' error, I found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithcsharp/thread/44e34afe-f308-4843-b3c6-7f00c55ce65d) on the MSDN forums.

In the end, Windows 8 does not bubble up exceptions to the app. The MediaElement silently fails, while all other video players run fine.

**The solution**: if you have Bootcamp on any Mac Laptop/Desktop, then go directly to the graphics manufacturer and download their latest drivers. For me, I have a MacBook Pro 17" and it uses the AMD Radeon 6600m series. The drivers can be [found here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/bootcamp-win7.aspx) for 64-bit versions.

Anyway, my apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Thanks @JimO'Neil for trying to help :)