# Windows 8 Store App - MediaElement no longer playing Audio

Tags: c#, xaml, audio, windows-8, mediaelement

I am trying to play an audio file (.wav) when a toggle button is pressed (and pause when pressed again). I had it working initially, but now I must of messed something up and am looking for help. This is how I'm doing it:

Create `MediaElement` in XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" PosterSource="vuvuzela.png" IsLooping="True" Source="Assets/vuvuzela.wav" Grid.Row="1" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

Then My `ToggleButton` is this:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Content="Activate" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="32" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle1}" Checked="Tog_Checked" Unchecked="Tog_Unchecked"/>
```

And in my Code-behind, I have the `ToggleButton`'s checked/unchecked handlers:

```
private void Tog_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void Tog_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Pause();
    }
```

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong or how to check it? Thanks!

---

EDIT: Debugged some more. Looks like the `myMediaElement` is not getting past the `Opening` state?

Comment: Just to let you know, it happens with my windows phone that sound doesn't work anymore until I reboot it. Started noticing that when my wake-up alarm didn't sound one day, and I couldn't play any sound on the phone until I restarted it. So maybe you ran into this weird system bug?

Comment: not a bad idea, but rebooting was to no avail

Comment: I noticed that setting autoplay to true in the toggle event/click event (whatever trigger) might do the trick. Try myMediaElement.AutoPlay = true; myMediaElement.Play();

Comment: @IrisClasson thanks but that did not seem to work either. Do you have any other ideas? the `MediaElement`is never getting Opened

Comment: I remember a similar issue a few months ago, the person did a VS repair, updated all the drivers for the computer and did a restart. Give that a try if you haven't already. Fingers crossed for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a hardware problem. My computer (MacBook running Bootcamp) was the issue. Finally found that answer in this post --> [MediaElement in WinRT / Win8 does not work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738382/mediaelement-in-winrt-win8-does-not-work-at-all)

Thanks for all the help though everyone

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to you that your media element be visual like that?

Try this in your click event instead:

```
var _Media = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement() { AutoPlay = false };
var _Location = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var _Folder = await _Location.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("Ding.wav");
var _Stream = await _File.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
_Media.SetSource(_Stream, _File.ContentType);
_Media.Play();
```

Comment: No it does not have to be visual I guess. I tried your code though and still got nothing. When I debug with breakpoints, the `CurrentState` of `_Media` is `Opening`. Never gets to `Play`. Does that mean something?

Comment: remove AutoPlay = false and it should work. If it is in the click event for a play button it doesn't need to be false anyway. Otherwise set to false in XAML and true before play in code.

Answer (score 0):

Have shown code required to play audio file. (code for playing next audio is bonus )

1.Add media element, play/pause/stop buttons to the XAML file.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="Assets/page1/para1.mp3"  
              Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  AutoPlay="True" />
<Button Click="StopMedia" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Stop" />
<Button Click="PauseMedia"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Pause" />
<Button Click="PlayMedia" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="Play" />
```

2.Add the following code to the code-behind file:

```
    private void StopMedia(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        media.Stop();
    }
    private void PauseMedia(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        media.Pause();
    }
    private  void PlayMedia(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        media.Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/page1/para1.mp3");
        media.Play();
    }

    protected override async void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        media.MediaEnded += media_MediaEnded;

    }

    private void media_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        media.Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/page1/para2.mp3");
        media.Play();
    }
```