# Why won't WinRT MediaElement.SetSource do what it should?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mediaelement

Very simple.  When using `MediaElement` this code works:

```
TestMedia.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Test.mp4");
TestMedia.MediaFailed += TestMedia_MediaFailed;
TestMedia.AutoPlay = true;
```

This code does not:

```
StorageFile fileToTest = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Test.mp4"));
var stream = await fileToTest.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
TestMedia.SetSource(stream, fileToTest.ContentType);
TestMedia.MediaFailed += TestMedia_MediaFailed;
TestMedia.AutoPlay = true;
```

No delegate methods are ever called and no exceptions are ever thrown (I know I am not assigning them here, but even if I do it doesn't matter).  It is simply blank.  Why won't `SetSource` work in place of `Source`?  The reason I ask is that I am trying to implement simple obfuscation of movie files so that someone using our app will at least have to put some effort into stealing the copyrighted content.  That requires altering the stream in memory before passing it onto the `MediaElement`

**EDIT** One more piece of relevant information is that the status changed callback on the Media Element gets called once in the second version (the status is immediately "Closed").

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: @bash.d I'm not following.  I boiled it down to this simple test case in which the expected behavior is different than what I expect.  `MediaElement` seems to be silently failing in the second case, even though in theory they are using the exact same file.  Other than that I can only debug if I get information from within `MediaElement`, which is not indicating anything.

Comment: I mean stepping through it... Sometimes you get different results and you might have a Timing Problem actually. Although this is really a simple case.

Comment: Yes, I have stepped through it, but all of the relevant details happen in places that I cannot step into (inside the Windows Runtime).

Comment: `Status Changed` of the `Stream`?

Comment: MediaElement's "CurrentStatusChanged" event gets called once for the second case (Closed) and twice for the first case (Opening, Playing).

Comment: So, then you should check on the stream and its state when you `SetSource`

Comment: CanRead true, CanWrite false, Position 0, Size 8225560 (This is the only available information about the stream)

Comment: What is `fileToTest.ContentType`? Have you checked on this? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244338.aspx) it must be `System.String`...

Comment: Yes, the ContentType is a string -> "video/mp4"

Comment: Try `TestMedia.SetSource(stream, "video/mp4");` it's working for me.

Comment: Try to replace `OpenAsync` with `OpenReadAsync`

Comment: This question looks very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738382/mediaelement-in-winrt-win8-does-not-work-at-all.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov Similar, but that person's fails even with the Uri version.  Mine works with the Uri version.

Comment: @bash.d It was originally OpenReadAsync and had the same result.

Comment: I am not facing ANY issues, with your code of question.

Comment: @Xyroid That is very discouraging.  I will try updating the graphics drivers on my machine.

Comment: This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ea27ffc7-0b8d-4211-8584-5cfa124fe58e) contain working example. They state that it may be a problem with immediate `TestMedia.AutoPlay = true;`.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov That was half of the problem!  The other half was me doing this stuff too fast.  I moved the code to inside the Loaded handler of the MediaElement and it is working well now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ea27ffc7-0b8d-4211-8584-5cfa124fe58e) the problem is `TestMedia.AutoPlay = true;` just after `SetSource`. It seems there should be some delay between these two methods.

Comment: @bash.d I don't see where you said this, could you point it out?