# Videos disappearing

Tags: video, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mediaelement

I have an application that has a high dependency on videos and it uses MediaElement to reproduce them.

However, I have introduced a layer that either gets a video from an external folder or an internal folder. Therefore, in my internal folder, I am loading my videos like this:

```
private static async void 
   InitVideo(MediaElement mediaElement, string resourceName)
   {
        try {
            Uri imageUri = 
                new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx:///{0}", resourceName),
                                      UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            StorageFile file = 
                     await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(imageUri);
            var stream = 
                     await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error loading video ({0})", resourceName);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and then in my XAML I have something like this:

```
lextensions:MediaElementExtensions.MediaResource="video1.mov"
```

MediaResource is an attached property that calls this when it changes:

```
MediaElement mediaElement = sender as MediaElement;
if (mediaElement != null) {
    mediaElement.Tag = args.NewValue; // pass the new resource name.
    mediaElement.Loaded += LoadVideo;
}
```

When the MediaElement is loaded the `LoadVideo` is called and that calls `InitVideo`.

This works fine a lot of times. However, in rare cases, this doesn't work and I have no idea why. I am using mov files with H.264 codecs.

I have seen that [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738382/mediaelement-in-winrt-win8-does-not-work-at-all) [people](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/44e34afe-f308-4843-b3c6-7f00c55ce65d) have this issue. However, in their case they weren't able to display any video at all. And I can do that. Actually, it works in more than 80-90% of the times.

Comment: First of all, you should not have your return type being an async void. That makes you Windows 8 app domain crash, if your code inside that method fails. That's also why you haven't caught any errors in your catch block, right ?. See this for more pointers http://bit.ly/13C8g9x

Comment: @danielovich that video actually made a lot of sense. I am going to try to replace every async void by async Task. I belive that solves it, right? Do you have any idea how can I test this? Never had a problem like this :)

Comment: good you got something out of it. I believe the video also explains pretty well how to structure your Tasks and async behavior. If you want to test it explicitly, try throwing an exception in for you try block, and see where it bubbles too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I didn't experienced the videos disappearing. I have updated the videocard drivers and take the considerations that @danielovich pointed out.

The moral is: Avoid async void. And [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only) does a good job explaining why.