# Media Element doesnot play at all

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am playing audio mp3 in my windows 8.1 app but media element doesnot playing any thing 
Here is my code

a.Play();

nothing happens,no errors shown.I am struggling for two days about this problem and I followed this link 
[MediaElement in WinRT / Win8 does not work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738382/mediaelement-in-winrt-win8-does-not-work-at-all)
and updated my driver still nothing happens . Please help me my graphics driver is Intel R(Q35) Express Chipset Family(Microsoft Corporation-WDDM 1.0) and processor is Core2Duo 2.666
Need Help?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem in few versions of Windows 8.1. Update your windows or install windows 7.

Comment: http://goo.gl/Gkx1sX
This will surely resolve your problem, this issue arrises in Windows 8.1 Enterprise N and Windows 8.1 Enterprise KN. Don't forget to mark my answer as yes if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample,

CodeBehind.cs

```
    MediaElement Sound= new MediaElement();
    Sound.Source = new Uri ("/Assets/Sounds/MySample.mp3",UriKind.Relative);
    Sound.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(Sound_Opened);
    Sound.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    Sound.Volume = 1;
    Sound.AutoPlay = false;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Sound);
    Sound.Play();

    void Sound_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement _Sound = sender as MediaElement;
        _Sound.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain little what is the problem in my code

Comment: You have a Grid in XAML, in this code creating a new media element and adding a Resource from the assets folder, you can put the file you want to play, and then adding to the layoung and play. Play method to start media playback. When opened, the media will be in Stopped state

Comment: You have not provided any code to find problem except a.Play() which seems to have no problem.

Answer (score 1):

After 5 days of struggle finally got the answer to install Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1

http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=40744

Comment: The Media Feature Pack is also needed in certain cases after upgrading to Windows 10. For anyone interested, get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231