# Media element not playing audio in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I want to play mp3 audio in my app but nothing is happening 
my code is this

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="SunnahForKids.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SunnahForKids"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="Black">

        <StackPanel Width="900" Height="700" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <MediaElement HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="a" AutoPlay="False" Source="azan.mp3" Height="100" Margin="451,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Volume="100"/>

            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,676,0" Height="189" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here is my .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Data.Json;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace SunnahForKids
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

       }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            a.Play();

        }


    }
}
```

and I am struggling with it for 2 days need help . I also followed this link [MediaElement in WinRT / Win8 does not work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738382/mediaelement-in-winrt-win8-does-not-work-at-all) 
to update my driver but it is up to date.Display driver in Intel R(Q35) express chipset family ( Microsoft Corporation WDDM-1.0) please get me out of here..

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the code works, so something strange is going on. I would try to listen for the events mentioned in the link (example further down for devs looking for code example).

Check your event log on the computer (Windows => Applications), if you've missed updates for windows, and check that that mp3 will otherwise play.

Listen for the MediaFailed event (recommend that you do in the docs) and see if you can grab some information there.[Code from msdn:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed)

```
private void videoMediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check the event arguments => e

    // get HRESULT from event args 
    string hr = GetHresultFromErrorMessage(e);

    // Handle media failed event appropriately 
}

private string GetHresultFromErrorMessage(ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String hr = String.Empty;
    String token = "HRESULT - ";
    const int hrLength = 10;     // eg "0xFFFFFFFF"

    int tokenPos = e.ErrorMessage.IndexOf(token, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (tokenPos != -1)
    {
        hr = e.ErrorMessage.Substring(tokenPos + token.Length, hrLength);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: videoMediaElement_MediaFailed method not fire